# Can't connect to server using Uvicorn

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, server, centos, uvicorn

I have a host with a public and private IP address.
I run on my server: `python3.8 -m uvicorn server:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000`

Obtaining:

```
INFO:     Started server process [5904]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:     Application startup complete.
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://0.0.0.0:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

However I can access it only via localhost. If I use the public IP address it is unreachable.
I'm using Amazon Aws Ec2 server with CentOS, should I check the settings there?
Thanks

Comment: Did you create firewall rules to allow this traffic?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Make sure that your EC2 security group is open for the port 8000 and also the Subnet Network ACL is open on port 8000 incoming and the ephemeral ports outgoing

Comment: @SándorBakos thank you so much! It was the security group!